# How to initialize UIView so that it covers screen on landscape mode?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm using the `initWithFrame` method for initializing a UIView that would act as a subview for the main view of the view controller; however, the UIView always seems to present itself based upon a portrait mode frame (thereby hugging itself to the side of screen) instead of a landscape mode frame where it would cover the entire screen.

I am initializing the view controller in landscape mode, so the uiview should be initialized with correct parameters, but that does not seem like the case right now. I have been using superview's frame, superview's bounds, and `UIScreen mainscreen` as possible arguments (rects) to `initWithFrame`, but I have had no luck so far.

Comment: 1. Your view controller is created using a xib/story board file in portrait mode ? 2. In what method do you `initWithFrame` your view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define proper `autoresizingMask` to your view after initialization.

First, initialize the view with its `frame` as your screen `bounds` (or your parent view's, if your parent view occupied the entire screen). Then, set your views `autoresizingMask` as follows:

```
self.myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

This should make your view change its `bounds` automatically when its parent's views `bounds` are changed.

Comment: This won't work every time, if the VC is created using a xib/stroyboard in portrait mode, and the view is init in viewDidLoad, the frame/bounds are still for portrait mode, and the `autoresizeMask` help only when the `parent` view will get resized.

Comment: Of course, that's because you shouldn't do any initializations that rely on your views' dimensions in `viewDidLoad`, but only in `viewWillAppear`.